# MySQL stored procedures in PHP with examples

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

Can someone help me to create stored procedures in MySQL and call them from PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-mysql-using-php-and-display-the-value-return-by-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create procedure very easily in MySQL --
Syntax :-

```
`//add a delimiter; 
Create Procedure <procedure_name>(parameters "IN(for using inside the procedure)" and "OUT(for returning)")
Begin
   // doing some thing.
end;
//end delimiter;`

Call Procedure - `CALL <procedure_name>(parameter1, parameter2, ....)`

Example -

`DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeName(IN EId INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpId = EID;  
END//`
```

Calling- assume i want to know the name of employee id "10", so --

`CALL EmployeeName(10);`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_user_login` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_user_login`(
  IN loc_username VARCHAR(255),
  IN loc_password VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

  SELECT user_id,
         user_name,
         user_emailid,
         user_profileimage,
         last_update
    FROM tbl_user
   WHERE user_name = loc_username
     AND password = loc_password
     AND status = 1;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and call by,
mysql_connection specification and

```
$loginCheck="call sp_user_login('".$username."','".$password."');";
```

it will return the result from the procedure.