# MySql stored procedure call with out parameter returns error on SqlFiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sqlfiddle

I have created the following stored procedure for MySql schema on **sqlfiddle**

```
create procedure foobar(out msg int)
begin
set msg = 100;
end//
```

When i run the query to access the out parameter using

```
call foobar(@outval);
SELECT @outval;
```

I get the following error

**ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.**

I am not sure what am i doing wrong. Please suggest.

I am taking this as reference [MySQL create stored procedure syntax with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786240/mysql-create-stored-procedure-syntax-with-delimiter)

Sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2182/6

Comment: In SQL Fiddle use the following trick in the stored procedure: `set msg = 100; select msg;`

Comment: @wchiquito Somehow the exact same code that was giving error earlier now works fine on sqlfiddle. Probably someone was working on the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `delimiter` at the start, so it should be as

```
delimiter //
create procedure foobar(out msg int)
begin
 set msg = 100;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Here is a test case in mysql cli

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure foobar(out msg int)
    -> begin
    ->  set msg = 100;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call foobar(@outval);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @outval;
+---------+
| @outval |
+---------+
|     100 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Why you need to execute the procedure on sqlfiddle ? Why not try on your mysql server ?

Comment: Because i cannot install mysql server locally (installation restrictions).

Comment: sqlfiddle may have many issues on a given time, and you really can't relay on it. If you want to learn then install mysql and try out.