# mysql different row updates depending on a variable (stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, sql-update

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_table(
    IN choice INT(4),
    IN id VARCHAR(50),
    IN string VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE salesman
set salesman_name = IF(choice = 1, string, salesman_name)
where salesman_id = id
UPDATE salesman
set date = IF(choice = 2, string, date)
where salesman_id = id
END
```

if `choice`is 1, change salesman_name as `string`

if `choice` is 2, change date as `string`

can you explain me what i'm doing wrong?

it works fine with a single `update`, my guess is there is another way to implement if but i couldn't.

```
if choice = 1 then
update salesman set salesman_name = string where salesman_id = id
```

...i tried this version too but still, not working.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_table(
    IN choice INT(4),
    IN id VARCHAR(50),
    IN string VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE salesman set salesman_name = IF(choice = 1, string, salesman_name) where salesman_id = id;
UPDATE salesman set date = IF(choice = 2, string, date) where salesman_id = id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1*

also says this:

*ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11* (last line)

Comment: Are you using the procedure editor interface in phpMyAdmin to do this? What have you selected in the text field for your delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

When a stored procedure has more than one statement, they need to be terminated with ;

To do that, you need to tempoararily change the delimiter so you can end the procedure. Here's a SO answer with an example of how to do that: [MySQL create stored procedure syntax with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786240/mysql-create-stored-procedure-syntax-with-delimiter)

Comment: He doesn't appear to be talking about a 1065 syntax error. Is he? Then again maybe he is. The whole thing is too vague.

Comment: yes i am. it says syntax error where second update starts (line 10) i've tried it with a delimiter too. now the syntax error is for `DELIMITER $$`

Comment: just found out the procedure is actually working when called with `CALL`... the error is for the last line only(where delimiter is set to ";" again)