# How to create stored procedures in SQL using cmd?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

This is what i tried.  I have table called crop, and want to create stored procedure of selecting   all in that table.

Here is the error i got:

```
MariaDB [sample]> CREATE PROCEDURE AllFarmers
    -> AS
    -> SELECT * FROM crop
    -> GO;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your  MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AS SELECT * FROM crop GO' at line 2

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Looks to me like you're coming from the SQL Server world. The MySQL stored procedure syntax is different. Read this to see an example. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html  Maddening, isn't it?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786615/2469308

Comment: Perfectly works. Thanks  Madhur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that the syntax is not correct on your procedure. You should replace AS by BEGIN and GO by END.

I put an example here

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE AllFarmers ()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Test;
END;
//
call allfarmers()
```

Try it and tell me if there is any problem

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE AllFarmers ()
SELECT * FROM Test;` is the [shortest](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYttLueYaRAu9CyZn2xJ5J/0) you can write in MySQL and MariaDB.. As single statements does not need to use `BEGIN / END` blocks and also there for not need to use a `DELIMITER`

Answer (score 0):

Might also be worth mentioning you can a drop to the start in case the stored procedure already exists:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AllFarmers`
```