# Create MySQL procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am currently trying to create a stored procedure on my MySQL stored on Google Cloud Platform.

The SQL is correct seeing that I can create the procedure locally, but I can't figure out why it won't work from the command line:

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE helpme
    -> (
    ->  @cid varchar(4)
    -> )
    -> AS
    -> DECLARE @res_cnt INT
    -> DECLARE @name CHAR(10)
    ->
    -> SELECT @res_cnt = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TripGuides WHERE GuideNum = @cid
    -> SELECT @name = LastName FROM dbo.Guide WHERE GuideNum = @cid
    -> PRINT @name + ' has ' +  CAST (@res_cnt AS VARCHAR(10))+' guides.';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@cid varchar(4)
)
AS
DECLARE @res_cnt INT
DECLARE @name CHAR(10)

SELECT @res_cn' at line 3
mysql>
```

I've tried a few different things thank I have bumped into. When declaring `@cid` I tried both

```
@cid CHAR(4)
@cid VARCHAR(4)
```

resulting in the same error being thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL create stored procedure syntax with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786240/mysql-create-stored-procedure-syntax-with-delimiter)

Comment: also `@cid` is a user variable, which are different from procedures arguments and `DECLARE` variables.

Comment: UDV cannot be used as parameter name. Use local variable.

Comment: @ danblack
No, unless you are saying I have to add DELIMITER to my call. I also want @cid to be a user defined variable.

Comment: @akina Im not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: you are getting syntax errors because `SELECT` statements aren't ending with`;`. Because `DELIMITER` isn't set you will get different syntax errors as the mysql client treats that as the end of the `CREATE PROCEDURE`. after you resolve that you will get the UDV errors, because they aren't the same as parameters or local variables. Also stored procedures and rarely offer any useful benefit, and are hard to debug. Avoid whenever possible.

Comment: @danblack Oh, I took out all the ; since it would auto run once it hit that location. But the delimiters will temporally stop that from happening. Thank you that's really good to know. I also feel like I'm using the wrong syntax all together for defining variables. 
instead of 
DECLARE #res_cnt INT
should I simple be placing
set #res_cnt = COUNT(*) FROM TripGuides WHERE GuideNum = #cid;

Comment: Please treat all # as @, stack overflow wouldn't allow me to place so many in one comment.

Comment: Please explain why you use SQL server syntax whereas in subj and tags you mark the question as MySQL-related?

Comment: @Akina well sir, its obvious that I'm not very versed in the topic. How ever I am trying to figure it out. So their a different syntax for SQL server and MYSQL?

Comment: Yes, their syntax is similar in base only.

Comment: While it's fun to learn how to do new stuff, and that's fine, I don't actually see anything 'procedural' here

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE helpme ( cid VARCHAR(4) )
SELECT CONCAT( ( SELECT LastName 
                 FROM Guide 
                 WHERE GuideNum = cid ), 
               ' has ', 
               ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                 FROM TripGuides 
                 WHERE GuideNum = cid ), 
               ' guides.'
             ) AS message;
```

> Just out of curiosity how would I go about declaring res_cnt and name as to the original SQL call i did before?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE helpme ( cid VARCHAR(4) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE res_cnt INT;
    DECLARE `name` CHAR(10);

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res_cnt FROM TripGuides WHERE GuideNum = cid;
    SELECT LastName INTO `name` FROM Guide WHERE GuideNum = cid;
    SELECT CONCAT( `name`, ' has ', res_cnt, ' guides.' ) AS output_message;
END
```

And do not forget about DELIMITER re-assign in that case.

Comment: So that did work but not till I removed the AS. But at the same time I'm not 100% sure why. So CONCAT( ) will allow me to add two SELECT calls together. Then the "AS message" will print what ever is in the CONCAT( )?

Comment: @dapi *that did work but not till I removed the AS* Yes, `AS` was excess - removed. *Then the "AS message" will print what ever is in the CONCAT( )?* No, `AS message` is added to make it easier to access it in the code (you may use the field name alias `message` instead of indexing number reference). The alias may be any valid, used `message` name is random.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would I go about declaring res_cnt and name as to the original SQL call i did before?

Comment: @dapi I do not see the reason to use intermediate variables when we may avoid this. But if you want - you may... in that case you must use BEGIN-END codeblock.