# create mysql store procedure gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

my mysql version is 5.7

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `newactivity`( IN _USERID INTEGER,  IN _ID INTEGER )
BEGIN

        SET @USERID = _USERID; 
        SET @ID = _ID;
        SET @OBJECTTYPE = 'activity';
        
END
```

it gives me error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

my line no 4 is below

```
SET @USERID = _USERID;
```

what is issue here, please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL create stored procedure syntax with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786240/mysql-create-stored-procedure-syntax-with-delimiter)

Comment: yes use of delimiter work for me, thank you