# how to call procedure with parameter in php page

Tags: php, mysql

i have the two table once main table another once audit table for back up process if delete the record only on audit... if the record was deleted from audit means then update status on main table.....
for example table structure of **main** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  0
```

for example table structure of **audit** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  0
```

here the status 1 is active and 0 is inactive

if i **delete** the record from the **audit** table 
then output like
for example table structure of **audit** table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
```

and
main table
for example table structure of audit table

```
id name status
==============
1 raj    1
2 arivu  2
```

if delete any record from audit table the record status is 0 or 1 just update it to 2

now i write procedure for solve the problem but i dont know how to call the procedure on php page
My Procedure is like

```
    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users` $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `users`(in id int(25))
    BEGIN

delete from person_history where id=id ;

update person set active='2' where id=id ;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

just like you would call a normal query

`call Procedurename('parameter')`

should work

Comment: in mysql query browser means we can use like this... but i need to call the procedure on php page.... anyone help me?

Comment: dude just call it as you would call a normal sql query from your php page, see the comments by the fellow stackoverflow'ians

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `mysqli_*`

`$result = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL users('$parameter')") or 
                                 die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
$id = 35; //hard coded, but you can replace this with a post or get var
$qry = "call users({$id});";
mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
```

Comment: then how to get the id value from query

Comment: In your stored procedure you send a numeric id as a parameter; based on the id your sent, you delete the history for that person, and later, you update the active field to 2...now what do you want to do?

Comment: i dont want hard code the id value.... depends upon the deletion i take the id.how can i pass id dynamically

Comment: I suposse you have some php script like a grid with a button or a link called "Delete History" for every user or something like that...how do you know the userid that you want to delete his history, it's in a session var, in a $_POST var??

Comment: it's in post variable only

Comment: i write procedure for delete from history and update the active field it's working fine in mysql query browser. i pass the id value statically means but i need to call from the php page and pass the id value dynamically

Comment: How that value looks in your php script...show me the code ;)

Comment: <?

$server1 = "localhost"; //Your MySQL Server
$user1 = "root"; //Your MySQL username
$pass1 = ""; //Password
$dbname1 = "demo";
$conn1 = mysql_connect($server1, $user1, $pass1) or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to ther serve
$db1 = mysql_select_db($dbname1, $conn1) or die(mysql_error()); //Select the database

  echo $result = mysql_query($conn1, 
    " CALL users($id)"));
echo "hi";
 

  /*//loop the result set
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){   
      echo $row['t_reg_id'] . " - " ; 
  }
*/
?>

Comment: You are not retrieving any id in your code...how do you know which id you want to pass to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

  //connect to database
  $connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db", "port");

  //run the store proc
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
     "CALL StoreProcName") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

  //loop the result set
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
      echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1]; 
  }

?>
```

Note : Above code has been taken from [How to call a MySQL stored procedure from within PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)