# php mysql stored procedure example

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

sorry for asking too much in this forum.

i'm creating a website using asp.net with mssql database
i know how to use and create stored procedures and views

but i changed the language to php and mysql
my question is i looked for examples online(using search engine google)
but i was shocked to see 3 or 4 examples only. and those are hard to understand
as a beginner like me

but there are many examples using the old way query like select * from tablename bla bla
but using encryption and validating user input(maybe to avoid sql injection)
my question is why there are small examples out there? 
why some example don't use stored procedure? and i even watched a tutorial from udemy and he uses the old sql way(don't know if its old or not just my term)
instead of stored procedure

can someone gave me a good link to read about crud using php and stored procedure(i can't find a good one for a beginner) thank you

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to go back to the search engine. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner I found you some articles that I think are easy to understand because they explain each concept very well.

- [Stored Procedure Basics (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)
- [PHP-MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/)
- [PHP-MySQL Stored Procedures 2](http://www.phpgang.com/mysql-stored-procedure-in-php_9.html)
- [Official PHP DOC for Stored Procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)
- [Example: call a stored procedure using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

I hope this helps you! :)