# MySQL insert multiple records with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple HTML form and some php variables as follows to submit book details to a MySQL table named Book using submit method. clcode is a auto increment field.

```
$isbn =$_POST["isbn"]; 
$bno =$_POST["b_no"];
$bname =$_POST["b_name"];
$qty =$_POST["qty"]; 
$price =$_POST["price"];
```

And need to insert records depending on the qty. eg:- If a qty=2, 
It needs to execute the insert query twice (Should be inserted 2 same records with auto increment clcodes). If a qty=5, 
It needs to execute the insert query 5 times (Should be inserted 5 same records with auto increment clcodes) and so on... I used a stored procedure and the following SQL query to do that.

```
$query ="CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
    DO
    INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES ('$isbn', '$bno', '$bname', '$qty', '$price');
        SET i = i + 1;
WHILE i < $qty;
    END WHILE;
END";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error());
```

But it is return a syntax error. I can not uderstand what I am going wrong. Pls. anyone can help me...? Tnx.

Comment: You are prone to sql enjections and please add some error logs

Comment: so you say `it is return a syntax error`, but you don't think it would have been a good idea to post it here with your question?

Comment: Should it insert two rows with qty = 1 if  post qty  is 2?. I assume your records should have N no of table rows with minimum scale of 1.

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure for this?

Comment: @Xtern find the answer. I have tested this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to create a procedure to meet your requirement.

Suppose it worked for first run, but create procedure will show error in next run because procedure is already there.

You just need to run insert query a number of times, or build insert query with multiple values and run once.
Here is what I think you should do.

Approach 1

```
for ($i=0;$i< $qty;$i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2,fieldn) VALUES ('field-val1','field-val2','field-valn')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error());
}
```

Approach 2

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2,fieldn) VALUES";

for($i=0;$i< $qty;$i++){
  $sql .= "('val1','val2','valn')";
  if($i < ($qty -1 )){
     $sql .=",";
   }

 }
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 6):

**Create table**

```
create table book (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  isbn VARCHAR(20) not null,
  b_no VARCHAR(20) not null,
  b_name VARCHAR(20) not null,
  qty INT not null,
  price decimal(8, 2) not null,
  primary key(id)
);
```

**Create SP**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_book (
  IN isbn VARCHAR(20),
  IN no VARCHAR(20),
  IN name VARCHAR(20),
  IN qty INT,
  IN price DECIMAL(8,2)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < qty DO
  INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES (isbn, no, name, qty, price);
  SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

**Test SP**

```
call proc_book('978-3-16-148410-0', '1', 'name1', 2, 10.00);
```

**Data in table**

```
+----+-------------------+------+--------+-----+-------+
| id | isbn              | b_no | b_name | qty | price |
+----+-------------------+------+--------+-----+-------+
|  1 | 978-3-16-148410-0 | 1    | name1  |   2 | 10.00 |
|  2 | 978-3-16-148410-0 | 1    | name1  |   2 | 10.00 |
+----+-------------------+------+--------+-----+-------+
```

**Call SP from PHP**

Use mysqli instead of mysql

```
<?php 
// input data should be filterd to prevent SQL injection etc.
$isbn  = $_POST["isbn"];
$bno   = $_POST["b_no"];
$bname = $_POST["b_name"];
$qty   = $_POST["qty"];
$price = $_POST["price"];

//connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db", "port");

//run the store proc
$sql = "CALL proc_book('" . $isbn . "', '" . $bno . "', '" . $bname . "', " . $qty . ", " . $price . ")";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());
?>
```

**Reference**

- [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)
- [Stored Procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)
- [MySQL WHILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/while.html)
- [How to call a MySQL stored procedure from within PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

Comment: Good explanation...Please check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/while.html) as well

Comment: @Zumry Mohamed I will add this reference as well.

Comment: You should consider implementing transactions if you add large qty. Please find the benchmark for 10000 qty.

Answer (score 0):

```
[begin_label:] WHILE search_condition DO
    statement_list
END WHILE [end_label]
```

this is what the syntax of while loop

For e.g.:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE i < $qty  DO
    INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES ('$isbn', '$bno', '$bname', '$qty', '$price');
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Try this one.

Comment: @ raveenanigam. But is returns syntax error like -> 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE myproc() BEGIN DECLARE i integer DEFAULT' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `CREATE PROCEDURE` in your query. You just want to `INSERT`. You should really be just looping in php to execute a prepared statement to perform the insert.

Read the PHP docs on using a mysqli prepared statement.

Comment: What's bad about creating a procedure for this task? does it slow? unsafe? ...?

Comment: As written, the OP's code creates a new procedure every time it is run, which is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0
while($qty >= $count){
    //insertion code goes here...
    $count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your sql statement :

```
$query = "DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE myproc() 
    BEGIN DECLARE i integer DEFAULT 0; 
    while (i< ".$qty.") do 
    begin 
    INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES (".$isbn.", ".$bno.", ".$bname.", ".$qty.", ".$price."); SET i = i + 1; end; end while; 
    END $$

    DELIMITER" ;
```

For more details visit: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Performance benchmark with and without transaction in SP.

**1.) Without transactions.**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_book (
    IN isbn VARCHAR(20),
    IN no VARCHAR(20),
    IN name VARCHAR(20),
    IN qty INT,
    IN price DECIMAL(8,2)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < qty DO
    INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES (isbn, no, name, qty, price);
    SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

*Try to add 1000 qty (without transactions)*

```
mysql> call proc_book('978-3-16-148410-0', '1', 'name1', 10000, 10.00);
Query OK, 1 row affected (8 min 43.01 sec)
```

**2.) With transactions.**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_book (
    IN isbn VARCHAR(20),
    IN no VARCHAR(20),
    IN name VARCHAR(20),
    IN qty INT,
    IN price DECIMAL(8,2)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    WHILE i < qty DO
      INSERT INTO book (isbn, b_no, b_name, qty, price) VALUES (isbn, no, name, qty, price);
      SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    COMMIT;

END;

DELIMITER ;
```

*Try to add 1000 qty (with transactions)*

```
call proc_book('978-3-16-148410-0', '1', 'name1', 10000, 10.00);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)
```