# Insert x rows into table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL i want to add around 1000 rows into a table. With PostgreSQL there is this statement that can be used to add x rows in your table.

```
INSERT INTO table(int_col) 
SELECT x.id
FROM generate_series(1, 1000) AS x(id);
```

I search for several solutions(like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930781/mysql-insert-multiple-records-with-while-loop)) and one of the options i to create a function with a [loop](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html). I don't fully understand how this works because i m very new to MySQL. The other option is to do this by hand with a insert statement like this.

```
insert into table(int_col)
values (1), (2), (3) etc etc.
```

But you can understand that this is way to much work for 1000 rows. I also dont have a txt or csv file with the data that i want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure and execute it to `bulk insert` rows into table, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bulk_insert()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 1000 DO
        INSERT INTO table (int_col) VALUES (i);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) is MySQL's documentation on stored procedures.

Comment: Thank You! this works for me