# Call a MySQL procedure with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call a procedure from my database to my a website by php but i cant get i t working.
herese the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS NewCannon; 
 DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE NewCannon(subPlaceName varchar(32), model char(4), status enum('on','off','unplugged','broken'),effect smallint)
BEGIN
insert into Cannon (subPlaceName, model, status, effect) values (subPlaceName, model, status, effect);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: More to the point probably would be the PHP code that's not work g, including a description of "not working." Please edit your question to include that and also format the code properly

Comment: Might be similar to [How To Call A MySQL stored Procedure within PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

Comment: test worked fine from mysql side, http://i.imgur.com/iDbcEoA.jpg , see YCS error avoidance (detection) via http://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488