# Execute stored procedure in sql server from php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a stored procedure in SQL Server and when I want to run it  there is no errors no result.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SonNum]  
    (@FiNo BIGINT,
     @TeNo BIGINT,
     @Dok INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DokNum BIGINT

    SET @DokNum = (SELECT DokNo 
                   FROM CH_SonNum 
                   WHERE FiNo = @FiNo AND TeNo = @TeNo AND Dok = @Dok)

    IF @DokNum = 0 OR @DokNum IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @DokNum = 1

        INSERT INTO CH_SonNum (FiNo, TesNo, Dok, kNo) 
        VALUES (@FiNo, @TeNo, @Dok, 2)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE CH_SonNum 
        SET Dok = Dok + 1 
        WHERE FiNo = @FiNo AND TeNo = @TeNo AND Dok = @Dok
    END

    SELECT @DokNum AS Dok
END
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php  

$FiNo= 1;
$TeNo=10;
$Dok=204;

$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[SonNum] '$FiNo','TeNo','$Dok';
$stmt =  sqlsrv_query( $conn,$sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code

Comment: No , i tested  that not works for me ,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's causing your issue but you're missing a `"` at the end of `$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[SonNum] '$FiNo','TeNo','$Dok';`

```
$FiNo= 1;
$TeNo=10;
$Dok=204;

$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[SonNum] '$FiNo','TeNo','$Dok'" //<-- You were missing a " ;
$stmt =  sqlsrv_query( $conn,$sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

?>
```