# Running multiple mySQL queries thru one connection

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys I am trying to run multiple queries thru mySQL and php and have not so far been able to figure it out... I read that mysqli_multi_query might be what I want and tried it as well with only the first query being run because I had them in this format.
"query";"query";"query" etc...so my last attempt was like this "query;query;query" etc and nothing happens can someone please figure out the syntax to get all 4 queries to run consecutively. here is the queries first then the php code.

```
INSERT INTO queue (SELECT NULL,item1, log, Active FROM shipping WHERE Active = 1);
DELETE FROM shipping ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE shipping SET Active ='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE shipping SET Active ='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

and here is the php..

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "logistics";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

 if (!$conn) {

die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO queue (SELECT NULL,item1, log, Active FROM shipping WHERE Active = 1);
   DELETE FROM shipping ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE shipping SET Active ='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE shipping SET Active ='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"


 if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

?>
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: `   UPDATE shipping SET Active ='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE shipping SET Active ='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"` what is the point in this?

Comment: UPDATE does not have a ORDER BY or LIMIT ????? Correct your SQL syntax

Comment: You also need to look up how to look for and react to potentially 4 success messages or an error being returned from one of these multi queries.

Comment: I would suggest you do this inside a TRANSACTION as 4 seperate single queries

Comment: I guess what I was asking since every one is complaining about my queries instead of what I was asking was how to run multiple queries regardless of what they think the point of it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the wrong syntax in `UPDATE` statement as already commented, you should consider pulling those SQL code into a Stored Procedure and call that procedure from your client code instead like

```
create procedure usp_doSome
as
begin
INSERT INTO queue (SELECT NULL,item1, log, Active FROM shipping WHERE Active = 1);
DELETE FROM shipping ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE shipping SET Active ='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE shipping SET Active ='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
end
```

Well on how to call a stored procedure from php, there are many example present. See below

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/

[How to call a MySQL stored procedure from within PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

Comment: If you can add a comment as to how to call a (the) Stored Procedure from PHP that would be great.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul will look into that.  I was hoping for a simpler answer like syntax adjusted but this is a starting point...real noob at all this thanx again.