# get output value from mysql stored-procedure to php?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

how i can get output value from stored procedure to php variable ..

example Stored procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE `test`; CREATE DEFINER=`mydbinstance`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(OUT `max` INT(11)) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN 
SELECT MAX(slno)+1 INTO @max FROM table1; 
SELECT @max; 
END
```

php:

```
$stmt=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL test();");
```

Comment: i feel upcomming bugs with race conditions if you use this value in a other queries..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a MySQL stored procedure from within PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the result(s) of a stored procedure the same way you would any other query:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn,"CALL test();");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($stmt)) {
    $value = $row[0];
}
```